# Magento change onepage checkout page title

Tags: magento

I need to change the checkout onepage title. I tried by adding below code into my custom layout file. But it did not work;

```
<checkout_onepage_index>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setData" translate="title"><key>title</key><value>your title </value></action>
        </reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

Can anyone help me please.

Thank You.

Comment: Are you using Magento default checkout?

Comment: Thank you for helping. Yes i am using Default checkout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="setTitle"><title>New Title</title></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: This way is the correct way to do. I had some other issues with my custom module. Solved the issue. Thank you so much for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Check once with the following

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="setTitle" translate="title"><title>Your Title</title></action>
</reference>
```

or via code by accessing head block element and calling `setTitle('your title')` method on it.

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle('your title'); \
```

Besides this in case, To customize titles or label values i.e. “Shipping Information” or “Zip Code” etc. in Magento Onepage Checkout page

open `app/locale/en_US/Mage_Checkout.csv`.

To change a value, simply locate the value that you want to change in column A and edit the text in column B to the text that you would like to be displayed for this label during checkout.

For instance, to edit the Shipping Information label, find “Shipping Information”,”Shipping Information” and replace with “Shipping Information”,”Your title”.

Remember to clear your cache in the Magento Admin Panel and then test the checkout to verify that the values for the titles or labels are displaying.

For more help check the  [link](http://inchoo.net/magento/change-any-page-title-in-magento/)

Comment: Hi thank you for helping. i tried first two solutions, but nothing worked for me. Can you tell me the exact event for these. Is it <checkout_onepage_index>

Comment: Both ways are correct ways to do. I had some other issues with my custom module. Solved the issue. Thank you so much for helping.